# Automatically add meta tags on node creation

Tags: 8, hooks, meta-tags

I'm currently maintaining a lot of different sites containing the same information pages (example: profile pages with the same content but on different sites/base URL) and I'd like to consolidate this into a single URL housing all the profile pages. However, the first phase of this task was to develop a way to automate a rel=canonical metadata tag on creation of a node.

What would be the best way to meet this requirement? Is there a hook I can use?

Comment: Install the Meta Tag module. It will set global defaults for entities, and also allow you to override that per item from their respective forms.

Comment: https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag

Comment: Thanks guys! I appreciate this greatly!